# PHP colorear tablas, filas y columnas

Tags: php, html, html5, bucle-for, html-tabla

¿Cómo podría estructurar el siguiente código de manera adecuada para conseguir estos resultados? Estoy algo perdido con el tema de PHP para "fusionarlo" con el html. Si es 4x4 muestra 16 números, los impares en verde y los pares en rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Dibujando tabla</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <?php
       if(isset($_POST["enviar"]) && (!empty($_POST["filas"])) && (!empty($_POST["columnas"]))) {
             $filas=$_POST["filas"];
             $columnas=$_POST["columnas"];
             $incremento=1;
             for ($j=1; $j<=$filas; $j++) {
                for ($i=0; $i<=columnas; $i++) {
                    $multiplica=$incremento*$i; 
                    echo $incremento. "x" .$i. "=" .$multiplica. "<br>"; 
                    print("<td>" .$incremento[$filas][$columnas]. "</td>");
                }
                $incremento++;
                echo "<br>";
             }
         }else {

           ?>
        <form name="formulario" action=' <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>' method="post">
        <div>
        <label for="name">Indica el número de filas: </label>
        <input type="number" name="filas"/> 
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for="name">Indica el número de columnas: </label>
        <input type="number" name="columnas"/> 
        </div> 

        <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="enviar">
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar" name="Borrar">

    </body>
</html>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Lo que no te sales es colorear la matriz?

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar tienes un error de sintaxis, te falta el `$` en el for de las $i (debe ser `$columnas`), por lo que veo en tu código generas las tablas de multiplicar, no hay nada relacionado con generar números pares ni impares, dicho esto a continuación tienes un ej. para pintar las columnas pares e impares adaptado a tu código de la tabla de multiplicar, haz los cambios para que se ajuste a lo que realmente necesites.

```php
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Dibujando tabla</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <?php
       if(isset($_POST["enviar"]) && (!empty($_POST["filas"])) && (!empty($_POST["columnas"]))) {
             $filas=$_POST["filas"];
             $columnas=$_POST["columnas"];
             $incremento=1;


             for ($j=1; $j<=$filas; $j++) {
                 echo '<table style="float: left; display: inline-block;">';
                        for ($i=0; $i<=$columnas; $i++) {

                            // define color para la columna par o impar la columna
                            $style = (($j % 2) == 0) ? 'color: red;' : 'color: green;';

                            $multiplica=$incremento*$i;
                            echo '<tr>
                                    <td style="'.$style.'">'.$incremento. 'x' .$i. '=' .$multiplica.$incremento[$filas][$columnas]. '</td>'.
                                '</tr>';

                            // otra opción para hacer el echo
                            //echo "
                            //<tr>
                            //    <td style='{$style}'>{$incremento}x{$i}={$multiplica}{$incremento[$filas][$columnas]}</td>
                            //</tr>";

                        }
                    $incremento++;
                 echo '</table>';
             }
         }else {

           ?>
        <form name="formulario" action=' <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>' method="post">
        <div>
        <label for="name">Indica el número de filas: </label>
        <input type="number" name="filas"/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for="name">Indica el número de columnas: </label>
        <input type="number" name="columnas"/>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="enviar">
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar" name="Borrar">

    </body>
</html>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilice el código que indicas y mi resultado fue:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dibujando tabla</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<?php

if((!empty($_POST["filas"])) and (!empty($_POST["columnas"]))) {
  $filas = $_POST["filas"];
  $columnas = $_POST["columnas"];
}else{
  $filas = 4;
  $columnas = 4;
}


$numero = 1;

$tabla = '<table border="1">';

for($i = 1; $i <= $filas; $i++) {

    $tabla .= "<tr>";

    for($j = 1; $j <= $columnas; $j++) {

        if($j % 2 == 0) {
            $tabla .= "<td style='background:red;'>Par ".$numero."</td>";
        }else{
            $tabla .= "<td style='background:green;'>Impar ".$numero."</td>";
        }

        $numero++;

    }

    $tabla .= "</tr>";

}

$tabla .= "</table>";

echo $tabla;

?>

    <form name="formulario" action=' <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>' method="post">
      <div>
        <label for="name">Indica el número de filas: </label>
        <input type="number" name="filas" min="0"/> 
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="name">Indica el número de columnas: </label>
        <input type="number" name="columnas" min="0"/> 
      </div> 
      <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="enviar">
      <input type="reset" value="Borrar" name="Borrar">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

La magia esta en el segundo **for** donde **evaluo** si es **inpar** o par dividiéndolo entre 2. Puedes verlo funcionar [aquí](https://www.onlinegdb.com/SkDuFqehm).